# Calling methods on datasource in displayoption lags screen and prevents records from showing

Tags: forms, axapta, x++

I have overridden the displayoption method on my forms datasource to display lines in red which don't have enough stock (based on stock position & released production orders) but I think calling several methods on the datasource (which are also used by display fields on my form) has such an impact on the drawing of my form that the lines are red but the data isn't shown:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{        
    ProdBom _prodbomlocal = _record;    
    if (this.DRS_GetLineAvailable(_prodbomlocal) < 0)
    {
         _options.backColor(8421631); //Light Red
    }
}
```

For instance when there are a lot of lines for which available stock, released production quantity, etc needs to be queried only one line is shown instead of e.g. 30 lines

I don't know what to do, is there some way I can pre-query the data?

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the `super()`?

Any computation in `displayOption` should be very fast, or your form will suck.

Do not use color code in decimal, at least use hex 0x8080FF (BGR code).

Comment: Thanks Jan (and Bull), guess I'm overdoing the computations / queries. Still doesn't work right. I'll do without the fancy colors for now, right values are displayed based on production order status that's the most important thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{        
    ProdBom _prodbomlocal = _record;    
    if (this.DRS_GetLineAvailable(_prodbomlocal) < 0)
    {
         _options.backColor(8421631); //Light Red
    }

    super(_record, _options);
}
```